# Character-matching queries in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I'm attempting to optimize a T-SQL stored procedure I have. It's for pulling records based on a VIN (a 17-character alphanumeric string); usually people only know a few of the digits—e.g. the first digit could be '1', '2', or 'J'; the second is 'H' but the third could be 'M' or 'G'; and so on.

This leads to a pretty convoluted query whose `WHERE` clause is something like

```
WHERE SUBSTRING(VIN,1,1) IN ('J','1','2')
AND SUBSTRING(VIN,2,1) IN ('H')
AND SUBSTRING(VIN,3,1) IN ('M','G')
AND SUBSTRING(VIN,4,1) IN ('E')
AND ... -- and so on for however many digits we need to search on
```

The table I'm querying on is *huge* (millions of records) so the queries I'm running that have this kind of `WHERE` clause can take *hours* to run if there are more than a couple digits being searched on, even if I'm only requesting the top 3000 records. I feel like there has to be a way to get this substring character matching to run faster. Hours are completely unacceptable; I'd like to have these kinds of queries run in just a few minutes.

I don't have any editing privileges on the database, sadly, so I can't add indexes or anything like that; all I can do is change my stored procedure (although I can *try* to beg the DBAs to modify the table).

Comment: How fast does a query run if you only pull back the first two digits (I get from your question that those are always known in the search)?

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound rude. You should post that with a story in Daily WTF :)

Comment: @progo - Not at all rude... it is government work after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
WHERE VIN LIKE '[J12]H[MG]E%'
```

At least that should hopefully lead to 3 index seeks on the ranges `JH%`, `1H%`, and `2H%` rather than a full scan.

**Edit** Although testing locally I found that it does not do multiple index seeks as I had hoped it converts the above to a single seek on the larger range `VIN  >= '1' and VIN  < 'K'` with a residual predicate to evaluate the `LIKE`

I'm not sure whether it will do this for larger tables or not but otherwise it may well be worth trying to encourage this plan with

```
WHERE (VIN LIKE 'JH%' OR  VIN LIKE '1H%' OR  VIN LIKE '2H%') 
        AND VIN LIKE '[J12]H[MG]E%'
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know this feature existed.

Comment: oh god yes that took like one minute

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) keyword

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Table
WHERE VIN LIKE '[J12]H[MG]E%'
```

This would even allow you to work with instance where they know the second character is not 'A' by using [^A] in the statement, such as:

```
WHERE VIN LIKE '[J12][^A][MG]E%'
```

Reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I like the `LIKE` answers, but here's another alternative (especially if your input isn't always the same).

I would do this as a series of queries on ever-smaller temp tables (Yes, I'm in love with temp tables- sue me.)

So I would do something like

```
SELECT [Fields]
INTO #tempResultsFirstTwoDigits
FROM VIN
WHERE [Clause]
```

Then keep moving down the chain digit by digit until you've searched each of the provided characters.  So you might do this:

```
if len(@input) > 2
SELECT [Fields]
INTO #tempResultsThreeDigits
FROM VIN
WHERE Substring(VIN, 3, 1) = Substring(@input, 3, 1)
//NOTE: That where clause might be sped up by initializing a variable at 
//      the beginning of the SP for each character you got.

Else Select * From #tempResultsFirstTwoDigits
GOTO Stop //Where "Stop" just defines the end of the SP to skip any further checks
```

Again, `LIKE` might be a better answer for you, but I would try both approaches and benchmark both of them.